# Converting a log file into a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following problem at work - I need to take a log file with items arranged as follows:

```
A1
B1
C1
A2
B2
C2
.
.
.
An
Bn
Cn
```

I need a complete csv file like so:

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
...
An,Bn,Cn
```

How can I do this using a python script?

EDIT: Actually, the format is written out in the following way -

```
Voltage: A1
Current: B1
Power: C1
```

How can I convert it to -

```
Voltage, Current, Power
A1,B1,C1
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post any code that you have written. Presumably your company is paying you, so you should show your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Say more about the format of the log file. If the format is exactly as you wrote, all you need to is find the value of `n` from the last line of the file then just create the csv file: no need to look at the rest of the log file. Or is there something you did not include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('myfile.log') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    lines = [lines[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]

    with open('yourcsv.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile)
        w.writerows(lines)
```

Note that the dots are still there and they would be treated as values (so they'll be separated by comma's too)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("d.csv", dtype=str)
data = np.reshape(data, (3,-1))
np.savetxt('data.csv', data, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
```

Result:

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
An,Bn,Cn
```

If you are not using numpy, please post some code that you have tried.