# string replace while writing from log to a csv

Tags: python, string, csv, replace

I am trying to convert a log file into csv using python ([mainly this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912556/converting-a-log-file-into-a-csv-file-using-python))

```
import csv

with open('/home/user/Downloads/my.log') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    lines = [lines[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]

    with open('test.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile)
        w.writerows(lines)
        print "done"
```

My original log file looks like this :

```
2017-08-09 -> 11:30:01
Temp=29.0*  Humidity=30.0%

2017-08-09 -> 11:40:01
Temp=29.0*  Humidity=33.0%
```

From above example code, I can convert it into this format

```
2017-08-08 -> 08:50:01,Temp=33.0*  Humidity=38.0%
2017-08-08 -> 09:00:01,Temp=37.0*  Humidity=40.0%
```

But I need my final csv to look like this

```
2017-08-08,08:50:01,33.0*,38.0%, 
2017-08-08,09:00:01,37.0*,40.0%
```

I have used `lines = lines.replace("->",",")` and I got

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

As I understood, python can not replace text file its being treated in memory. So what I can do? what method I can use to purify the final text?

My python knowledge is not advance, still learning. So if there a mistake or missed step, please correct me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try: lines = [i.replace("->",",") for i in lines]

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Full modified code

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/my.log') as file, open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [','.join([i.strip() for i in lines[x:x+2]]) for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]
    lines = [i.replace("->",",").replace(" ","").replace("Temp=","").replace("Humidity=",",") for i in lines]

    outfile.write("Date,Time,Temp,Humidity")

    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Outputs

```
Date,Time,Temp,Humidity
2017-08-08,08:50:01,33.0*,38.0%
2017-08-08,09:00:01,37.0*,40.0%
```

---

**Wokring Example**

```
datafile="""2017-08-09 -> 11:30:01
Temp=29.0*  Humidity=30.0%

2017-08-09 -> 11:40:01
Temp=29.0*  Humidity=33.0%"""

lines = io.StringIO(datafile).readlines()
lines = [','.join([i.strip() for i in lines[x:x+2]]) for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]
lines = [i.replace("->",",").replace(" ","").replace("Temp=","").replace("Humidity=",",") for i in lines]
lines
```

Returns:

```
['2017-08-09,11:30:01,29.0*,30.0%', '2017-08-09,11:40:01,29.0*,33.0%']
```

Comment: @Sachith What do you mean? I added a header for convenience here: **outfile.write("Date,Time,Temp,Humidity")**

Comment: @Sachith I adapted my code to work with your example. You made a list and forgot to "".join that list into a string before doing replacements.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a list of strings:

```
lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

And then this creates a list of lists of strings:

```
lines = [lines[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]
```

Replace works on a string, not a list. There are many ways to solve this:

```
# 1. do replace on original string, before splitting.
lines = file.read().replace("->", ",") 

# 2. or do replace on elements of list, before creating list of lists
lines = file.read().splitlines()
lines = [i.replace("->",",") for i in lines]

# 3. or replace on each element in list of lists 
# (not implemented)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `replace` as a list method since `lines` is a list containing the strings, if you want to transform it use `map` or a `list comprehension`:

```
lines = [i.replace("->",",") for i in lines]
```

or

```
lines = map(lambda x: x.replace("->",","), lines)
```

You can chain the transformations to get the final result:

```
lines = map(lambda x: x.replace("->",",").replace("Temp=", "").replace("  Humidity=", ",").replace(" ", ""), 
            lines)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/KCmo/0)

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` method can be invoked on string, not on list, so `lines.replace("->",",")` is incorrect. You can operate on a whole text from file, and next split it into lines:

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/my.log') as file:
    text = file.read().replace("->", ",")
    lines = text.splitlines()
    lines = [lines[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to using regular expressions?  If so, extract groups 1, 2, 3, and 4 from each string with the following pattern:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) -> (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),Temp=([0-9.]+)\*\s+Humidity=([0-9.]+)
```

([see it working here](https://regex101.com/r/jA4Ram/2/))

You'd use the `re` library.

```
import csv
import re

with open('/home/user/Downloads/my.log') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    lines = [lines[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(lines), 3)]

    pattern = '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) -> (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),Temp=([0-9.]+)\*\s+Humidity=([0-9.]+)'

    with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("Date,Time,Temp,Humidity\n")
        print("Date,Time,Temp,Humidity")
        for line in lines:
            m = re.search(pattern, line)
            f.write("{}, {}, {}, {}\n".format(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4)))
            print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4)))
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of regex, however somestimes I thnk it is overkill. +1

Comment: Totally agree.  And, it's sometimes slower than a more simple approach.  In your case, given how rigidly the formatting is on your log files, you can break the lines up over content that you know always will be found between your data values.  If you couldn't count on the rigidity, though, this is an especially good solution.